# sass --watch is not watching partials

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sass

I seem not to be able to make sass watch changes in my partials, so it is only when I make changes to my main scss file that the css file is compiled.

I have a folder with my m.scss and m.css file and a subfolder to that called partials with my partials in. So:

- m.css
- m.scss
- partials/_base.scss

I have tried:

```
sass -I partials --watch m.scss:m.css
```

But does not work.

I am on a mac with an ubuntu server running on paralels and running Haml/Sass 3.0.15 (Classy Cassidy)

Comment: why not watching your whole folder for changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way I got this to work was to go to just do a watch on the folder with my primary css in. So if your css folder is call "css" then:

```
sass --watch css
```

That compiles m.scss into m.css everytime a scss file in the folder or a subfolder is changed

Comment: When I call --watch css it gives me this error: `sass --watch css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
WARNING on line 2 of css:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
      error css (Line 4: Invalid property: "Backtrace:" (no value).)
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.` Do you maybe know what is that about?

Comment: @Kunok It says in the error message what the problem is